# Помогите найти ошибку с Jasmine?

Tags: jasmine

**Expected ({ 0: HTMLNode, length: 1 }) to be '#container'.**

```
    describe("Experimentation", function() {
var elem;

beforeEach(function() {
    elem = $('<div id="container"><p>Hello World</p></div>');
})

it("allows us to search with CSS selectors", function() {
    expect(elem).toBe('#container');   
})

});
```

Comment: Проверил ваш код на http://tryjasmine.com/ все работает. Тест не проходит если `id` контейнера не является `container` и проходит если является

Comment: Еще я включила jquery lib. Проблема может быть от каких то библиотек?

Comment: ну без jquery у вас не сработает запись `$()`. А значит тест уже свалится из за `undefined`. Все должно работать. Может вы используете старую версию Jasmine? Т.к. на тестовом все работает

Comment: У меня 2.4.1 последняя версия. А вот jquery.js  файл я скапировала с GitHub.

Comment: Ну у меня мало информации. Что-то вы делаете не так) Попробуйте заново повторить все по офф инструкции `jasmine`. PS. `копирование`, а не `капирование`

Comment: Извините за мой плохой русский )))  и спасибо за помощь!!!

Comment: Ничего страшного и удачного коддинга

Comment: Василий Барбашев спасибо.

Comment: Я нашла решения этой проблемы следующим способом.  
Чтобы эти тесты прошли нужно будет заменить 'toBe' с 'toEqual' и 'toContain' с 'toContainElement'.  Теперь все номально работает. ))   'ToBe' работает только на версиях jasmine 1x.